Maximal Torus of $l$-adic monodromy group.
I am trying to understand the $l$-adic monodromy group associated to the $l$-adic Galois representation of a $g$-dimensional abelian variety $A$ over a number field $K$. Then:
$$\rho_{A,l}:\operatorname{Gal}(\bar K/K)\xrightarrow{}  GL_{2g}(\mathbb{Q}_l)$$ is the above mentioned representation and the $l$-adic monodromy group $G_{A,l}$ is defined as the Zariski closure of the image of $\rho_{A,l}.$
By extending the base field we may assume that $G_{A,l}$ is a reductive group and in this case I have the following question:
If $u$ is a place of good reduction for $A$ and $T_u$ is the Zariski closure of an element in $\rho_{A,l}(\operatorname{Frob}_u)$ can we say that $T_u$ is a maximal torus inside $G_{A,l}$ if and only if the group generated the the eigenvalues of $\rho_{A,l}(\operatorname{Frob}_u)$ is a free abelian group?
It seems to me that this should hold but I am having a bit of trouble writing it down and showing it explicitly.
Any ideas would be much appreciated !!
